# Adding data to record in attributes table using ArcGIS Online

Tags: fields-attributes, arcgis-online

I am a new user of ArcGIS Online. I am trying to add data to an existing attribute table in Classic Maps.

Adding the field (column) was easy but I just can't figure out how to populate it with data. This is new data not a calculation of existing columns - I need to add in a category for each island.
[image: attributes table]

I have discovered that clicking on the cell in the table to try and input the data does not work and have done multiple searches online but can find noting about adding the actual data in for each row (I am possibly using the wrong terminology or logic).

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On the item details page for the layer containing the attribute table you are wanting to modify, navigate to the 'Data' tab. This will give you a full screen display of the attribute table that will allow easy editing of cells within the table.